# Karma Cucumber configuration

Tags: javascript, plugins, cucumber, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I really want to get karma and cucumber to run together. I have been using the karma-cucumber-js-latest adapter found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-cucumber-js-latest

My issue is that, I don't understand where karma is incorporated here. The reason I want to use cucumber and karma together is because my organization has already configured a heavy karma.conf.js file that is mapped to hundreds of dependencies, but this karma-cucumber-js project doesn't seem to give much importance to this karma.conf.js file either way? It's like its just running cucumber with JavaScript. Any changes I make to the karma.conf.js make zero difference, since the package.json file looks like this:

```
 {
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "cucumber": "5.0.2",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec src/test/javascript/*.js && cucumber-js ./src/test/resources/features/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "~2.9.11",
    "browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.3",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.3.0",
    "chalk": "~1.1.1",
    "cucumber": "^5.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-angular-filesort": "~1.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
     .....
```

running the test just runs cucumber-js for the relevant files.. where does karma come into play here?
Does anyone have experience getting karma and cucumber to work together? There are veryyyy limited resources online and I really need some insight!

Comment: I am also interested in knowing how to integrate cucumber-js into karma. I've been able to run it using `karma-cucumber-js-latest` but haven't been able to make it actually work. I've opened two issues in their repo where you can take a look at my setup: https://github.com/mitcoding/karma-cucumber-js-latest/issues/2, https://github.com/mitcoding/karma-cucumber-js-latest/issues/1